# How to add numbers after decimal using php

Tags: php, number-formatting

I am having trouble thinking of a php function to add zeros after a decimal. Let say I have $money="10000" I need a function that will add .00 to 10000.00 and to add just a zero to 0 after 234.5.
can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 13):

Just as Dan Grossman said; [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) is your friend here and you'd accomplish those double zeros by:

```
$money = "1234";
$formatedNumber = number_format($money, 2, '.', '');
echo $formatedNumber;

// 1234.00
```

Answer (score 9):

The function is number_format

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Always search the PHP manual first :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the answer you want to hear, but I think you're better off storing these values in numeric types and formatting them properly just before output

Comment: And may be he is formatting numbers specially for output? ;-)